# Inheriting from std::string

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdstring

So I have this:

```
class myString : public std::string{

public:

    void translate(){
        std::string phrase = blarg;

        ... Code ...

        blarg = phrase;
    }
```

Now, I know it's not blarg, but what would I have to put here to access the string associated with the myString string inheritance?

In a main outside of this, I could do:

```
myString phrase;
phrase = "Roar";
```

So how do I access the "Roar" in my function?

Everything is included properly.

Comment: `std::string phrase = *this;`?

Comment: You are not supposed to do this.

Comment: I feel dumb, lol. is it possible for someone to explain why it's *this? I would like to apply this to other things later, so it would be nice to know why it's *this

Comment: You want to copy the value of your object into a string.

Comment: I suspect you want `(*this) = blarg;`. As far as I am aware this kind of inheritance is fine as long as you don't add any member variables (or other destructor requirements) to your subtype. Can anyone clarify that for me?

Comment: Ooops I think you need: `*static_cast<std::string*>(this) = phrase;` (forgot to cast).

Comment: @Galik If a derived class with no `virtual` destructor is `delete`d through a base class pointer you'll end up with undefined behavior regardless of whether it has members or not ([expr.delete] 3).

Comment: @user657267 Not if using `shared_ptr` for one level of inheritance..

Comment: @Bradon If you mean something like `std::shared_ptr<std::string>{new myString};` then this is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @user657267, the limitation on `delete` through base pointer is not specific to `std` containers, it applies to all class hierarchies. Subtyping does not require `virtual` destructors. E.g., if we only intend objects to be created on the stack, then `delete` through base pointer is never an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the object with the `this` pointer.

```
class myString : public std::string
{
    public:

    void translate()
    {
        std::string phrase = *this;
        /*
        ... Code ...
        */
        *static_cast<string*> (this) = phrase;
    }
}
```

Comment: it really doesn't like doing *this = phrase;... any ideas? I have the class in it's own namespace, could that be a problem?

Comment: @blackbeltJR: fixed. This is a skeleton class. Normally if you did something like this you need a conversion constructor of the for `myString::myString(std::string const & ref) : std::string(ref) { }`

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a way to do it using the = operator.

Comment: I would prefer a `static_cast` or an  explicit call to `operator=`

Comment: @JohnDibling, you are correct on the `static_cast` operator, of course. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**You are not supposed to do this.**

But here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class myString : public std::string{
public:
    using std::string::string; // inheriting the constructors from std::string
    void translate(){
        // `std::string phrase = *this` won't work because no such constructor takes `myString` exist
        std::string phrase(this->c_str(), this->length()); 

        phrase += "2";

        // operator= won't work because type doesn't match
        // it is expecting `myString` type but not `std::string`
        this->assign(phrase); // use assign instead of operator=
    }    
};

int main()
{
    myString m = "test";
    std::cout << m << '\n'; // test
    m.translate();
    std::cout << m << '\n'; // test2
}
```

[online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98f851c7673b8d6a)

Comment: Looking at the answer above yours, why doesn't *this = phrase; work? I tried this->assign(phrase), which works, so thanks.

Comment: if you read the [error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b070c69362fb7117) it will tell you exactly what's wrong

Comment: "You are not supposed to do this." <- Says who?  I don't recall std::string being made into a final class.

Comment: @MrEricSir [If a derived class with no virtual destructor is deleted through a base class pointer you'll end up with undefined behavior regardless of whether it has members or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372334/inheriting-from-stdstring/26372470#comment41401839_26372334)

Comment: @BryanChen Good point, that could be dangerous if used incorrectly.  Too bad std::string doesn't have a virtual d'tor!

Comment: @blackbeltJR, the reason that `*this = phrase;` is incorrect is that the copy assignment operator for myString hides the copy assignment operator for std::string base class. You can resolve this by placing `using std::string::operator=;` in the myString declaration. Paragraph 13.5.3.1 of the standard: "Because a copy assignment operator operator= is implicitly declared for a class if not declared by the user (12.8), a base class assignment operator is always hidden by the copy assignment operator of the derived class."